# DRBD config difference between device and disk

Tags: ubuntu, drbd

I am configuring DRBD but I don't understand what the difference is between device and disk.

In the config file I have the following:

```
 on server1 {
            device /dev/drbd0;
            disk /dev/sda;
            address IP HERE;
            meta-disk internal;
    }
```

I don't understand what the difference is between disk and device and how do I find the name of each?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`disk` - is the underlying block device, i.e. a physical disk.

`device` - is the logical block device assembled from a set of disks (including those over network).

If you follow the analogy with RAID, the disk - is the physical disks, and the device is a RAID array.

That means that you have to specify `disk`s which you are intended to make a DRBD array. And the device you just pick `/dev/drbdX` (where X is a number starting from 0) which will be your logical block device after the DRBR are up & running. When you work with `/dev/drbdX` as with raw block device (disk), the DRBD will handle all the stuff for the redundancy & networking.

Comment: Thank you...That answers my question.